# jQuery Navigation - Same View, New Content

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-mobile

I'm using Ruby on Rails to build a simple web application and just recently added jQuery mobile to it plus a user-string regex to identify the phone (see Railscast 199).

Right now I'm having trouble with the following design problem: There exists a header that contains two links (left button and right button) each corresponding to the previous and next day respectively. I need them to link to the same view, but with ne content. In doing so, I've designed the following coffeescript to simply append a parameter to the page, which the Rails app then identifies and re-renders with new information.

```
$(document).ready ->
    m = parseInt $("#main")[0].getAttribute("data-message")

    $("a#m_previous").click ->
        move -1

    $("a#m_next").click ->
        move 1

    move = (direction) ->
        m += direction
        window.location = '/?data=' + m`
```

Which works fine. The buttons previously mentioned have links pointing towards '/'. But what this does is just refresh the page, instead of completing a forward/back animation like I'd like. This requires jQuery mobile to navigate to a new page, which it isn't doing.

**So my question is this**: How do I configure header buttons to move forwards/backwards and also render a new view but with the same information?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but take a look at the [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/). You can use it to load a portion of content into another page element.

```
$('#main').load('/?data=' + m + ' #content');
```

This would replace the content inside the main div with the content element.

Comment: Well, in that case the response is the whole page. I'm using jQuery mobile here. So I have the #content div wrapping everything that I use in the view (and change upon clicking a link). Therefore, I've adapted my javascript as follows: --[pastie link](http://pastie.org/1732932)--

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Matt, you're missing a space between the quote and the # `m + ' #mobile_view'` I've updated your pastie http://pastie.org/1732977 as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. What it does is replace the entire block of '#mobile_view" with a h1 that says "loading". All of the resources get fed in, but the replacement and transition simply doesn't work. Is there a callback or something? I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Matt, yes there is a callback, as per the documentation